# HTML5 Web Components with Polymer - loading external Stylesheets in template

Tags: html, web, polymer

Heyo, i've got a problem using a `<link rel="stylesheet" src="test.css" />` in a `<template></template>` in my custom polymer-element. I've imported and loaded everything relevant to use polymer. The error i get when trying to load external stylesheets is the following:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'cacheStyles' of undefined styles.js:38**

This error occurs when i try to load a stylesheet like follows:

```
- @import "test.css";
- @import url(test.css);
- @import url("test.css");
- @import url("http://localhost/misc/test.css");
- @import url(http://localhost/misc/test.css);
- @import "http://localhost/misc/test.css";
- <link rel="stylesheet" src="http://localhost/misc/test.css" />
- <link rel="stylesheet" src="test.css" />
```

All of the above methods of loading an external stylesheet fails with the mentioned error. Does someone have any suggestion i can still try out?

PS: It works when i hardcode it into the custom element but i'd like to add more than 500 lines of css for the element because it's a multilevel push menu i'm developing

Cheers, Gbeschbacher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds the same as https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/441.

Unfortunately, the bower 0.2.1 release incorrectly pointed used Polymer/platform 0.1.4 instead of 0.2.1, which had this `cacheStyles` API change.

I fixed the incorrect bower dependencies, but I had to modify the version tag, and anyone who tried to update in between will have a bad copy.

The solution is to delete the `bower_components`, run `bower cache clean`, then `bower install` again.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I posted this question in some other places (github doc issue, google group etc. - i'll update those posts and post this link as answer!) PS: Saw you already did that - thanks a lot!!